# How do I add a node or new element in SQL Server using XQuery and the xml datatype

Tags: sql-server, xquery

This is my example SQL Server XML

```
DECLARE @abc varchar(max),@Settingsxml XML,@DoesDefExist varchar(10)

SELECT @Settingsxml='<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <sys:Int32 x:Key="abc">1200</sys:Int32>
  <sys:Int32 x:Key="xyz">300</sys:Int32>
  <sys:Int32 x:Key="ghi">300</sys:Int32>
  <sys:String x:Key="def">Forgot your login or password? Please contact the IT Dept.</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>'
```

I would like to add the node `<sys:Int32 x:Key="def">300</sys:Int32>` after the `Key="abc"` element

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with code something like this:

```
-- declare a table variable to hold the data
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, XmlContent XML)

-- insert your XML into that table variable
INSERT INTO @table(XmlContent) VALUES(@Settingsxml)

-- define the relevant XML namespaces and UPDATE the table
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' AS ns,
'clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib' AS sys,
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' as x)
UPDATE @table
SET XmlContent.modify('insert <sys:Int32 x:Key="def">300</sys:Int32> after (/ns:ResourceDictionary/sys:Int32[@x:Key="abc"])[1]')
WHERE ID = 1

-- now, your XML stored in the table variable contains the new element where you wanted to have it
SELECT XmlContent FROM @table
```

The output in the end is:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <sys:Int32 x:Key="abc">1200</sys:Int32>
  <sys:Int32 x:Key="def">300</sys:Int32>
  <sys:Int32 x:Key="xyz">300</sys:Int32>
  <sys:Int32 x:Key="ghi">300</sys:Int32>
  <sys:String x:Key="def">Forgot your login or password? Please contact the IT Dept.</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as given by [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) but using `set` on XML variable instead of update on table variable. Can't use `with xmlnamespaces` here so ...

```
set @Settingsxml.modify('declare default element namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
                         declare namespace x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"; 
                         declare namespace sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib";
                         insert <sys:Int32 x:Key="def">300</sys:Int32> 
                         after (/ResourceDictionary/sys:Int32[@x:Key="abc"])[1]')
```

Comment: Interesting.... I kept trying to do it this way, but I used `SELECT @settingsxml.modify(....)` and kept having errors..... why didn't I think of `SET` instead!?!?!? :-)

Comment: @marc_s - I knew `SET` would work but I had to struggle a bit with the syntax for the namespaces. Relly wanted to use a default namespace. It was too late last night but I figured it out now.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to query if the "abc" node exists plus how to add "def" after "abc"
Here is the entire code below

```
DECLARE @abc varchar(max),@Settingsxml XML,@DoesDefExist varchar(10)

SELECT @Settingsxml='<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <sys:Int32 x:Key="abc">1200</sys:Int32>
  <sys:Int32 x:Key="xyz">300</sys:Int32>
  <sys:Int32 x:Key="ghi">300</sys:Int32>
  <sys:String x:Key="def">Forgot your login or password? Please contact the IT Dept.</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>'  


SELECT @DoesDefExist=@Settingsxml.value('declare namespace hrn="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
                          declare namespace x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml";
                          declare namespace sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib";
                          /hrn:ResourceDictionary/sys:Int32/@x:Key="def"','varchar(10)')

IF (@DoesDefExist='false')
BEGIN
SET @Settingsxml.modify('declare namespace hrn="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
                          declare namespace x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml";
                          declare namespace sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib";
                          insert <sys:Int32 x:Key="def">300</sys:Int32> after
                          (/hrn:ResourceDictionary/sys:Int32[@x:Key="abc"])[1]')
END       

SELECT     @Settingsxml
```